# jquery livesearch?

Tags: jquery, filtering, live, search

I am looking for a nice quick live search/filter.

Anybody use this? http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/quicksearch/#usage
Also how do you combine it with pagination or ajax for large amounts of data?

Code:

HTML:

```
<form method="get" autocomplete="off" action="">
<input type="text" value="" name="q" id="q"><br><br>
</form>
<ul id="posts">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#q').liveUpdate('#posts');
```

Using this as plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.liveUpdate = function(list){
  list = jQuery(list);

  if ( list.length ) {
    var rows = list.children('li'),
      cache = rows.map(function(){
        return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      });

    this
      .keyup(filter).keyup()
      .parents('form').submit(function(){
        return false;
      });
  }

  return this;

  function filter(){
    var term = jQuery.trim( jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase() ), scores = [];

    if ( !term ) {
      rows.show();
    } else {
      rows.hide();

      cache.each(function(i){
        var score = this.score(term);
        if (score > 0) { scores.push([score, i]); }
      });

      jQuery.each(scores.sort(function(a, b){return b[0] - a[0];}), function(){
        jQuery(rows[ this[1] ]).show();
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[For John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/), [comment for John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/#comment-318828), [quicksilver plugin](http://orderedlist.com/demos/quicksilverjs/javascripts/quicksilver.js)

[For John Nunemaker](http://orderedlist.com/articles/live-search-with-quicksilver-style-for-jquery)

Comment: Ok, it will be necessary to include some example for that can help you